# Minus sign too big in superscript inside subscript in math display mode

Tags: math-mode, subscripts, superscripts

The following code:

```
Inline mode $\|f\|_{H^{-1}}, \|f\|_{_{H^{-1}}}, \|f\|_{_{\scalebox{0.7}{$H^{-1}$}}},\|f\|_{_{\scalebox{0.5}{$H^{-1}$}}}$, 
display mode $$\|f\|_{H^{-1}}, \|f\|_{_{H^{-1}}}, \|f\|_{_{\scalebox{0.7}{$H^\{-1}$}}},\|f\|_{_{\scalebox{0.5}{$H^{-1}$}}}$$
```

Results in the following:

[image: Result]

I want to have `$H^{-1}$` as a sub-index, in the first case it is just too big to be a subindex.

I added a second subindex in the second, the H looks good, but the -1 is just too big, in particular the minus sign.

I added scalebox, in the last two cases, which seems to give a better looking result, and it actually scale correctly the term H^{-1}, but I hate to use it, I can see this failing once I have to modify this for other formats, but I'm not sure.

Is there a way to tell that minus sign to scale appropriately with respect to the sub-index level used?

---

It seems that one way to solve the problem is to correctly set the norms either by grouping or defining a norm command as perfectly shown in some answer.

I still found that the minus sign is too big in what follows:

```
\begin{equation}
  \begin{aligned}
    &f^{-1}(x) &&L_{f^{-1}}[\eta] \\
    &f(x)   &&L_{f}[\eta]
  \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
```

[image]

The "-1" sign takes even more width than the "f" in the first case, in the seconds it gets close to the width of the $L_f$.

I imagine I could use a different symbol, i.e. a minus in $1-2$ could be different that in $-1$.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of editing the title of your posting, as I believe the main issues are not about the size of the "minus" sign in the subscript terms. Feel free to revert if you disagree with my action.

Comment: @Mico even though my example has the norm, I found the minus sign to be too big in other cases like when attached to an inverse function, I guess I could use a different symbol to express the "minus" not as a binary operation "1-1" but just "-1". I will revert the title and add the example with inverse as well.

Comment: Is your main concern, then, with the size of the "minus" sign in compound sub/super-script subformulas? Please advise.

Comment: @Mico Yes, I'm mostly concerned with the width taken by the minus sign, in super-scripts and compound sub/super-scripts formulas. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Your best bet may be to define a couple of macros like this -- `\newcommand{\mym}{\mkern-1.5mu-\mkern-3mu 1}`  and `\newcommand\finv{f^{\mym}}` -- and then write `$L_{\finv}[\eta]$`. Note that this approach simply reduces the amount of whitespace around the scriptscript-style `minus` symbol. It does *not* reduce the size of either the minus symbol or the digit `1`.

Comment: I've updated my answer to incorporate your comment that your main concern is not the vertical positioning of the subscript terms but the spacing around the scriptscript-style `-` ("minus") symbols.

Answer (score 4):

(I revised this answer thoroughly after receiving additional comments from the OP.)

I think there are *two issues* that need to be addressed: One is the spacing around the `-` ("minus") sign when it occurs in scriptscript-style math mode, and the other is the vertical positioning of the subscript formulas that follow a "norm" (double vertical bar) symbol.

Regarding the first issue, I suggest you define some macros like this

```
\newcommand{\mym}{\mkern-1.5mu-\mkern-3mu 1}
\newcommand\finv{f^{\mym}}
\newcommand\Hinv{H^{\mym}}
```

and then write `$L_{\finv}[\eta]$` instead of `L_{f^{-1}}[\eta]`. Note that this approach simply reduces the amount of whitespace around the scriptscript-style minus symbol. It does *not* reduce the size of either the minus symbol or the digit 1; I'm concerned that reducing the size of the scriptscript-style glyphs would also reduce their basic readability. If you think the compressed `-1` still takes up too much space, you should probably coming up with new and space-saving notation to denote the inverse of a function. E.g., something like `f*` or `\bar{f}`...

Regarding the second issue: Note that the formula `\|f\|_{H^{-1}}` may be broken down into two sub-formulas: `\|f\|` and `_{H^{-1}}`. What you're encountering is that TeX has special rules for placing subscripts that follow a "math atom" such as `\|`: The subscripts (and superscripts) are set in a cramped mode. While this is OK in most settings, it's clearly not optimal for your use case. I can think of two remedies: Either change the first sub-formula from `\|f\|` to `{\|f\|}`, changing its type to "math-ordinary", or -- more LaTeX-ishly -- define a macro called `\norm` (say) using the machinery of the `mathtools` package, and then write `\norm{f}` instead of `{\|f\|}`.

Combining the solutions to the two issues, I think you should write `\norm{f}_{\Hinv}` instead of `\|f\|_{H^{-1}}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for "\DeclarePairedDelimiter" macro
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\norm\lVert\rVert     % create a "\norm" macro
\newcommand{\mym}{\mkern-1.5mu-\mkern-3mu 1} % short for "my minus one"
\newcommand\finv{f^{\mym}}
\newcommand\Hinv{H^{\mym}}

\begin{document}
$L_{f^{-1}}[\eta]$ vs.\ $L_{\finv}[\eta]$

\bigskip
\emph{Original code}

\quad$\|f\|_{H^{-1}}\quad\|f\|_{\Hinv}$

\bigskip
\emph{Employ grouping}

\quad${\|f\|}_{H^{-1}}\quad{\|f\|}_{\Hinv}$

\bigskip
\emph{Dedicated \emph{\texttt{\textbackslash norm}} macro}

\quad$\norm{f}_{H^{-1}}\quad\norm{f}_{\Hinv}$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

What you probably want is adding a (possibly empty) superscript, which will push down the subscript.

Here's an augmented version of `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` that does it:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools} % for \DeclarePairedDelimiter
\usepackage{xparse}    % for \NewDocumentCommand
\usepackage{booktabs}  % for the table

\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\normAux}{\lVert}{\rVert}
\NewDocumentCommand{\norm}{sO{}me{_^}}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {\normAux*{#3}\normS#4}
    {\normAux[#2]{#3}\normS#4}%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\normS}{mm}{%
  \IfValueT{#1}{_{#1}}^{\IfValueT{#2}{#2}}%
}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}

\begin{tabular}{lll}
\toprule
Style & New & Old \\
\midrule
Inline
  & $\norm{f}$ & $\|f\|$ \\
  & $\norm{f}^{2}$ & $\|f\|^2$ \\
  & $\norm{f}_{H^{-1}}$ & $\|f\|_{H^{-1}}$ \\
  & $\norm{f}_{H^{-1}}^{2}$ & $\|f\|_{H^{-1}}^{2}$ \\
\midrule
Display
  & $\displaystyle\norm{f}$ & $\displaystyle\|f\|$ \\
  & $\displaystyle\norm{f}^{2}$ & $\displaystyle\|f\|^2$ \\
  & $\displaystyle\norm{f}_{H^{-1}}$ & $\displaystyle\|f\|_{H^{-1}}$ \\
  & $\displaystyle\norm{f}_{H^{-1}}^{2}$ & $\displaystyle\|f\|_{H^{-1}}^{2}$ \\
\midrule
Sizes
  & \multicolumn{2}{l}{%
      $\norm[\big]{f}_{H^{-1}},\norm[\Big]{f}_{H^{-1}},\norm*{\dfrac{f}{2}}_{H^{-1}}$%
    } \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

(Beware: the syntax for the `e` argument type might change.)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I would complete the answer from Miko. Why it works? Why `${\|f\|}_H$` behaves differently than `$\|f\|_H$`? The answer is in TeXbook, page 445, paragraphs 18a and 18b. Roughly speaking, when nucleus (i.e. the object which is subscripted) is single character, then the subscript is lowered by `\fondimen16` independent of the depth of the nucleus. But if the nucleus includes more characters then the depth of nucleus is measured and the subscript is lowered by this depth plus `\fondtimen19`. The reason of this feature is our requirement that we need to have subscripts of `$a_2, f_2$` in the same vertical position.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, I can see why it makes sense in text mode to keep the subscripts and superscripts aligned, but I can't see why in math mode the same is true. For terms like  $H^1$, $L^p$ and so on, I found the superscripts are to  close to the mid part of the symbol. 

In terms like $u^m$ it looks fine, but in $u^m \in L^p$ I prefer to have no alignment of superscripts, and have the p raised, do you know how to make latex to behave the same as if there is a group with a single character? Beside using vphantom.